# Java Timer logic

Tags: java, dropwizard

This is some code which i found where we need to measure the query execution time for each queries ?
For measuring that `metricRegistry.timer` is used but how it works which time it measures as i can't find any line of code which define stop time  it just this line?
can anybody help me with that can't find anything on the internet ?

```
 try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY.SQL())) {
          try (
               Timer.Context ignored = metricRegistry.timer(name("query", QUERY.NAME())).time();
               ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
              successCounter.inc();
            } else {
              failedCounter.inc();
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: You always find detailed information inside the documentation. Please take a look at the following link - maybe you will find your answer there: https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/core.html#timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Timer.Context` is a `Closeable`, which means that when you use it in a `try` block like you have here, its `close()` method is called when the `try` block is exited.  Furthermore, per the Javadocs for `Timer.Context` (https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.Context.html), calling `close()` is like calling `stop()`.  So basically, `stop()` is called on the timer when the `try` block is exited.